# NavigatetoURL Community Article Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

How does navigatetoURL works in community Page.We have built a custom lightning component to display list of articles .TO redirect the article to the article page how to does navogatetoURL works in community where the community URL will be
/s/article/artilce-urlname

```
    ({
      getArticles1: function(component) {
      var action = component.get("c.getArticles");

    action.setStorable();

    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
      var state = response.getState();

      if (state === "SUCCESS") {
        component.set("v.articleview", response.getReturnValue());
      }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
  }
});


 navigate: function(cmp, event, helper) {
 console.log("test1")
    cmp.find("navService").navigate({

        type: "standard__knowledgeArticlePage",
        attributes: {
            "articleType": "How_To__kav",
            "urlName": "/article/"+{urlName}


            },

        } 
                                   )
    }

<aura:iteration var ="articleview" items="{!v.articleview}">
    <div>
    <p class="astyle"><a class="slds-text-color--default" onclick="{!c.navigate}" >{!articleview.title}</a></p>
</div>
```

Comment: where you want use `navigatetoURL` functionality, do you have URl column in your custom lightning component to display list of articles?

Comment: Yes ,we display a list of articles with URl in the lightning component .When the article is clicked it should redirect to the community page by using "onclick" and navigatetoURL in JS controller. @sdandamud1

Comment: The documentation is pretty straightforward on using the event, where exactly are you stuck?

Answer (score 0):

your component must implement the `lightning:isUrlAddressable` and must to use `lightning:navigation` i recommended to go through this [doc](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_page_definitions.htm)

cmp

```
<lightning:navigation aura:id="navService"/>

<aura:iteration var ="articleview" items="{!v.articleview}">
    <div>
    <p class="astyle"><a class="slds-text-color--default" onclick="{!c.navigate}" >{!articleview.title}</a></p>
</div>
```

controller:

```
({
    navigate: function(cmp, event, helper) {
        cmp.find("navigation").navigate({
            type: "standard__knowledgeArticlePag",
            attributes: {
                "articleType": "c__componentB",
                "urlName": "/article/"+{your url Name}


                },

            } 
        }, true); 
    }
})
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into it .Tried the above approach but the onclick to redirect to articlepage(https://xxxx.force.com/community/s/article/urlName) is not working.IS it possible to redirect by Using navigateToURL with articleURLname like in the below example   https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/139965/lightning-component-for-community-navigate-to-record-detail-page

Comment: i don't think so `force:navigateToSObject` works in your scenario, it works only for sobject with Id, can you update your question with what you tried so far and what error you getting when is use my solution?